# Error when using views on a linked server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, view, linked-server

I have this query:

```
SELECT
    -
FROM -.dbo.tb1
WHERE 
    -IN
    (
        SELECT 
            CASE 
                WHEN EXISTS
                (
                    SELECT * 
                    FROM -.dbo.tb2U1 WITH (NOLOCK)
                    WHERE col1 = '8614'
                )
                THEN
                (
                    SELECT TOP (1)
                        CASE WHEN ISNULL(col2,0) IN (1,2,3,6,8) 
                            THEN '2'
                            ELSE '1'
                        END AS col3
                    FROM -.dbo.tb1U1 WITH (NOLOCK)
                    LEFT join -.dbo.tb3U2 WITH (NOLOCK)
                        ON U1.-= U2.-  
                    WHERE 
                        -= '8614'  
                    ORDER by 
                        -DESC
                )  
                ELSE '3'
            END
    );
```

When I run it on `-`, it's ok. It returns me what I want:

```
col2
-------------------------------------------------- Value
```

But if I run it on `-` (we have the same database `-`, but with no tables, only views redirecting to `-` with the same names of the tables) it shows me this error:

```
Msg 8180, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Statement(s) could not be prepared. 
Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 An expression of non-boolean type specified in a 
context where a condition is expected, near 'THEN'.
```

The views to the linked server are of the form:

```
SELECT * 
FROM -.-.dbo.tb2
```

If I write the query without the `SELECT` here:

```
...Where -in ( ***NO SELECT HERE*** Case When Exists
(Select * from -.dbo...
```

...it runs perfectly.

I just want to know why this happens. How could this be possible? It's the same query.

Comment: http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: Minor rants: The `IN (SELECT CASE ... END)` can be simplified to `= CASE ... END` and the `ISNULL()` can be removed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bug, though one that only arises in very specific circumstances.

SQL Server uses a component called Distributed Query (DQ) to build T-SQL commands to run against the linked server. The optimizer transforms a `CASE` expression including a sub-select to a form that works perfectly well on local objects, but which is not translated correctly to remote query form (in this particular circumstance).

The bug results in a remote node being generated that requires the result of *local* computations. An internal query tree is created that expects these computed values as parameters, but no parameters are generated. This bug only occurs if the sub-selects are not correlated to the outer query (as is the case here), because a simplification that is only safe for a local query is applied.

DQ generates the remote query with parameters (using standard `?` syntax), but no parameters are passed, causing the `"statement cannot be prepared"` error (a prepared statement is the technical name for a parameterized statement).

If subquery contained an outer reference (correlation) instead of literal values, the local-only simplification would not be applied, and the query tree would be correct.

**Reproduction**

Create a linked server `SQL2008` to another instance of SQL Server 2008, which contains the `AdventureWorks` sample database. Create the following views on the local instance:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.Product AS
SELECT * 
FROM SQL2008.AdventureWorks.Production.Product AS P;
GO
CREATE VIEW dbo.TransactionHistory AS
SELECT *
FROM SQL2008.AdventureWorks.Production.TransactionHistory AS TH;
```

Generate an *estimated* execution plan for the following query (running it will just produce the error message, of course):

```
SELECT 
    P.ProductID 
FROM dbo.Product AS P
WHERE P.ProductID IN
(
    SELECT -- Comment this
        CASE 
            WHEN EXISTS 
                (
                    SELECT * 
                    FROM dbo.TransactionHistory AS TH 
                    WHERE TH.ProductID = 1 -- Not correlated
                )
            THEN 
                (
                    SELECT TOP (1) 
                        TH.TransactionID 
                    FROM dbo.TransactionHistory AS TH 
                    WHERE 
                         -- Not correlated
                        TH.ProductID = 1
                    ORDER BY 
                        TH.TransactionID DESC
                )
            ELSE 0
        END
);
```

The estimated query plan below highlights the problem operator:

[image: Estimated plan]

The `Remote Query` property of that operator is:

```
SELECT "Tbl1001"."ProductID" "Col1019" 
FROM "AdventureWorks"."Production"."Product" "Tbl1001" 
WHERE CASE WHEN ? THEN ? ELSE (0) END = "Tbl1001"."ProductID"
```

Notice the `?` parameter markers. The unresolved parameters generate the second error message when the remote server tries to compile `WHEN ? THEN ?`.

If you comment out the marked `SELECT`, the transformation in question is not applied, and the erroneous remote query is not generated.

Equally, replacing either of the `TH.ProductID = 1` instances with a correlation, for example `TH.ProductID = P.ProductID` also generates correct remote queries.

This bug reproduces in all current versions of SQL Server, up to and including SQL Server 2014 RTM CU4.

Comment: Hey paul, thank you very much. for sure i will study this. But i could manage my problem with a simple sp_updatestats TABLE.

i think the statistic of the database was corrupted ( i dont know how to say this in english, but we were without energy for some hours ), and you can see this when i remove the "select" and it works ( i think the SQL is not using that statistic anymore, and then, it uses another one). Thank for.

Comment: @RafaelPiccinelli Different statistics could easily cause the optimizer to choose a different plan option, yes. The problem could well come back in future though, so probably best to remove the `SELECT`, just in case.

Comment: Hey @paulwhite, same problem today. Solved removing the SELECT as you said. Hehe thank you again.